# More joins or more columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very basic question, which would be a more efficient design, something that involves more joins, or just adding columns to one larger table?

For instance, if we had a table that stored relatives like below:

```
Person  |  Father  |  Mother  |  Cousing  | Etc.
________________________________________________
```

Would it be better to list the name, age, etc. directly in that table.. or better to have a person table with their name, age, etc., and linked by person_id or something?

This may be a little simplistic of an example, since there are more than just those two options.  But for the sake of illustration, assume that the relationships cannot be stored in the person table.

I'm doing the latter of the two choices above currently, but I'm curious if this will get to a point where the performance will suffer, either when the person table gets large enough or when there are enough linked columns in the relations table.

Comment: The answer is it depends.  If you intend this to be scalable in the future or if the requirements are set and expected to never change.  Few joins is *generally* better from a performance standpoint, however Good database design tells you to separate common elements.  This design doesn't scale well if a person has a step father, mother, more than one cousin etc.  it's also de-normalizing data that could be easier to query if it was just 3 columns PersonID, RelationID, RelationTypeID, EffectiveDate, EndDate  This way you could scale with grater ease and know when people "lost" the relationship

Comment: Until you have several tens of gigabytes of data, performance is moot. Design and normalize your data, to be an accurate model of the world you are simulating. The time you save in programming will dwarf any small losses in performance, if they can even be detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a much more flexible design to separate out the details of each person from the table relating them together. Typically, this will lead to less data consumption.

You could even go one step further and have three tables: one for people, one for relationship_types, and one for relationships.

`People` would have all the individual identifying info -- age, name, etc.

`Relationship_types` would have a key, a label, and potentially a description. This table is for elaborating the details of each possible relationship. So you would have a row for 'parent', a row for 'child', a row for 'sibling', etc.

Then the `Relationships` table has a four fields: one for the key of each person in the relationship, one for the key of the relationship_type, and one for its own key. Note that you need to be explicit in how you name the `person` columns to make it clear which party is which part of the relationship (i.e. saying that A and B have a 'parent' relationship only makes sense if you indicate which person *is* the parent vs which *has* the parent).

Comment: Thanks for the help, this makes perfect sense

Answer (score 2):

Id' go for more "Normality" to increase flexibility and reduce data duplication.

```
PERSON:
ID
First Name
Last Name

Person_Relations
PersonID
RelationID
TypeID

Relation_Type
TypeID
Description
```

This way you could support any relationship (4th cousin mothers side once removed) without change code.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you plan to use the data a better structure may be

- a table for Person ( id , name etc )
- a table for relationships (person_a_id, person_b_id, relation_type
  etc)

where person_a_id and person_b_id relate to id in person
sample data may look like

Person

```
 ID Name 
  1 Frank
  2 Suzy
  3 Emma
```

Relationship

```
  A B Relationship 
  1 2 Wife
  2 1 Husband
  1 3 Daughter
  2 3 Daughter
  3 1 Father
  3 2 Mother
```